# TSQL Aggregating values based on other column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, aggregate

I have a table that looks as follows

```
Amount  Factor  Month   Customer
1       1       2       A   
3       1       2       A
4       -1      2       A
2       1       2       B   
2       1       2       B
3       -1      2       B
4       1       3       A   
5       1       3       A
6       -1      3       A
```

I want to aggregate (sum) the column `Amount` per `Month` and `Customer`. The `Amount`s should be multiplied with the value in the column `Factor`.

Hence, the result should look as follows (could be an `UPDATE` to the same table or a new table):

```
Amount  Factor  Month   Customer
0       1       2       A   
1       1       2       B   
3       1       3       A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT SUM(Amount * Factor) as Amount,Month,Customer
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Month,Customer
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
select month, customer, sum(amount * factor) as sum_amount
from t
group by month, customer;
```

I'm not sure why you would want `factor` in the result set.

Comment: The `Factor` seems to be a mere `SUM`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/61217/3